# Windows Batch CMD windows Closes fast even with Pause at end of File

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file which has the content

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-4" %%A in ("REG QUERY HKCU\Environment\") DO (
    echo %%A %%B 
)
pause
```

However when I run this, a cmd window opens like I expect but it closes very fast, before I can read the text. What can I do to prevent this, and why is it happening.

Comment: Shouldn't happen (and doesn't happen on my machine). I would recommend opening a command prompt manually and then run your batch file to see what it does and if it gets to the pause, or put a pause at the start of your batch file to see if that works.

Comment: And what's happens when you change " by '

Comment: Does `assoc .bat` say it's associated with `batfile`? Is `ftype batfile` defined as `"%1" %*`?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't happen on my machine too, you can also try to run from command line:

cmd /K your_file.bat

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1*" %%A in ('REG QUERY HKCU\Environment\') DO (
    echo "%%A" "%%B"
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Independtly of what the code does (as indicated by Hackoo, probably the inner double quotes should be single quotes), looking at the observed behaviour it seems there is a problem with `cmd` extensions. The default configuration is usually extensions enabled, but if extensions are disabled the `for /f` is not recognized as a valid command and batch execution is ended.

Try with

```
setlocal enableextensions
FOR /F "tokens=1-4" %%A in ('REG QUERY HKCU\Environment\') DO (
    echo %%A %%B %%C %%D
)
pause
```